# when computing integrals are all u-substitutions permitted or is there some conditions that need to be satisfied?

Tags: definite-integrals, substitution

for example let's compute this elementary definite integral$$I = \int_{-1}^{1}x^2dx = \frac{x^3}{3}|_{-1}^{1} = \frac{2}{3}$$
that's pretty simple. ok.

now let's say I use the following u-substitution $u = x^2$

the integral becomes of the following form : $$I = \int_{1}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{u}}{2}du$$

here the limits of integration are both $1$ so $I = 0$

why am I getting such a contradiction ? is it because $x^2$ isn't bijective on the interval $[-1,1]$ ?

Comment: Exactly, $x\to x^2$ is a generically $2$-to-$1$ map from $[-1,1]$ to $[0,1]$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown more generally when using a u-substitution
$u =\phi(x)$ only $\phi$ needs to be bijective and of course continuous,
 there's no other conditions ?

Comment: It helps if it's differentiable too.

Comment: Look that in your substitution you need to take the inverse of $x^2$ in order to change the term dx. But there is no inverse if the function isn't bijective in that interval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calculation is incorrect as $\sqrt{x^2}\ne x$ when $x<0$. But we can still use this substitution if we handle the signs carefully.

Note that if $x<0$, $\sqrt{u}=\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=-x$.

If $x\ge0$, $\sqrt{u}=x$

Let $u=x^2$. Then $du=2xdx$.

\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1x^2dx&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^0x(2x)dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1x(2x)dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_1^0(-\sqrt{u})du+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\sqrt{u}du\\
&=\int_0^1\sqrt{u}du\\
&=\left[\frac{2}{3}u^\frac{3}{2}\right]_0^1\\
&=\frac{2}{3}
\end{align}